# IO sequence Haskell

Tags: haskell, io

I have this function:

```
sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
sequence [] = pure []
sequence (op:ops) = do
    x <- op
    xs <- sequence ops
    return (x:xs)
```

which just writes a sequence of IO actions.

The problem is that I want to write the same function, but without using the 'do notation' at all, just using the operator >> and >>= instead.

I already have this version:

```
mySequence:: [IO a]-> IO [a]
mySequence [] = pure []
mySequence (op:ops) =
    op >> sequence ops
```

but it does not work for example with the input [ pure 1 , pure 2 ].

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the `do` version you have 2 bindings and a return statement. In the version without `do` you use `>>`, which discards the result of its left operand and the only thing you ever return is `[]`. The `do` version also uses the `:` operator, which the `do`-less version does not.

Answer (score 3):

In applicative notation, it's quite simple:

```
sequence (op:ops) = (:) <$> op <*> sequence ops
```

Im monadic notation, just translate `do` while keeping its structure:

```
sequence (op:ops) =
   op             >>= \x ->
   sequence ops   >>= \xs ->
   return (x:xs)
```

Roughly, `x <- action; ...` becomes `action >>= \x -> ...`. Note that the scope of the lambdas above extends until the very end of the expressions. With explicit parentheses:

```
sequence (op:ops) =
   op >>= (\x -> sequence ops >>= (\xs -> return (x:xs)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
If we call the function like: sequence [ putStr "hi" , pure 4] ,
this does not work, why?

Comment: @AntonioSerrano What would be the type of `[ putStr "hi", pure 4]`? `putStr "hi"` and `pure 4` have incompatible types, you can't put them in the same list (unless you create an `instance Num ()`, I suppose).

Comment: Okay, I got this, but why with the example [pure 1, pure 2] still does not work? @sepp2k

Comment: @AntonioSerrano `sequence [pure 1, pure 2]` produces `pure [1, 2]`. What makes you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Firstly, trying this: sequence (op:ops) =
   op >>= (\x -> sequence ops >>= (\xs -> return (x:xs))) with sequence [pure 1, pure 2] , the console says "main: main.hs:7:1-78: Non-exhaustive patterns in function mysequence ".
Secondly, when I solve this, with that example the console does not show anything, that's why I say it does not work.
What result do you get? Thanks @sepp2k

Comment: @AntonioSerrano I type `sequence [pure 1, pure 2]` into GHCi and get `[1, 2]` as the result (because GHCi automatically unwraps IO). When you do something like `main = sequence [pure 1, pure 2]; return ()` in a program, then nothing will happen because the sequence has no side-effect - all the elements are pure after all.